# Why does my DataForm not return as an object that my URL.createObjectURL is supposed to read?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, photo, multer

All I am trying to accomplish is to give my users the option to upload images. I decided to use mongoDB as my database which means I must store photos locally and then send them to the DB. As far as I know, I am new. The object created by ImageName and ImageData isn't being passed properly to my axios post request

```
                .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/image/uploadmulter/`, imageFormObj)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.data.success) {
                        alert("Image has been successfully uploaded using multer");
                        this.setDefaultImage("multerImage");
                    }
                })
```

Here is my route

```
const Image = require('../models/imageModel');
const ImageRouter = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) =>{
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype ==='image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    } else{
        //rejects storing file
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{
        fileSize:1024 *1024 * 5
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

// stores image in uploads folder using multers and creates a reference to the file

ImageRouter.route("/upload")
    .post(upload.single('imageData'), (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        const newImage = new Image({
            imageName: req.body.imageName,
            imageData: req.file.path
        });

        newImage.save()
        .then((result)=>{
            console.log(result)
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                document: result
            });
        })
        .catch((err)=> next(err))
    });

module.exports = ImageRouter;
```

here is my model

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    imageName:{
        type: String,
        default: "none",
        required: true
    },
    imageData: {
        type :String,
        required: false
    }
});

const Image = mongoose.model('Image' , ImageSchema)

module.exports = Image;
```

Here is my ImageUploader page that calls the function

```
import axios from 'axios';
import DefaultImg from '../assets/default-img.jpg';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';



export default class ImageUploader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            multerImage: DefaultImg
        }

        
    };

    setDefaultImage = (uploadType) => {
        if (uploadType === "multer")  {
            this.setState({multerImage: DefaultImg});
        };
    };

    // function to upload image once it has been captured include multer and
    // firebase methods

    uploadImage(e, method) {
        let imageObj = {};

        if (method === "multer") {

            let imageFormObj = new FormData();

            imageFormObj.append("imageName", "multer-image-" + Date.now());
            imageFormObj.append("imageData", e.target.files[0]);
            console.log(imageFormObj)

            // stores a readable instance of the image being uploaded using multer
            this.setState({
                multerImage: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
            });

            axios
                .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/image/uploadmulter/`, imageFormObj)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.data.success) {
                        alert("Image has been successfully uploaded using multer");
                        this.setDefaultImage("multerImage");
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    alert("Error while uploading image using multer");
                    this.setDefaultImage("multer");
                });

        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-container">
                <h3 className="main-heading">Image Upload App</h3>

                <div className="image-container">
                    <div className="process">
                        <h4 className="process__heading">Process: Using Multer</h4>
                        <p className="process__details">Upload image to a node server, connected to a
                            MongoDB database, with the help of multer</p>
                   
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            display="block"
                            className="process__upload-btn"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            onChange={(e) => this.uploadImage(e, "multer")
                            }/>
                    
                        <img
                            src={this.state.multerImage}
                            alt="upload-image"
                            className="process__image"/>
                           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

and finally this is where it's being rendered

```
// import {EditProfile} from './EditProfile'
import DisplayCats from '../cats/DisplayCats'
// import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Axios from 'axios';
import ImageUploader from '../ImageUploader';



function ProfilePage(props) {
    console.log(props.userInfo)

    const user = props.userInfo
    console.log(user)
    console.log(user._id)
    console.log(props.userInfo._id)

    let [responseData,
        setResponseData] = useState('');

    // getLocation = () => {
    //     navigator
    //         .geolocation
    //         .getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    //             console.log(position)
    //         });
    // }

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        this
            .props
            .history
            .push('/DisplayCats')
    }

    // const setProfileImage = (event) => {

    //     Axios
    //         .post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/updateImage/' + user._id, {

    //             "_id": user._id,
    //             "profileImage": event.target.value
    //         })
    //         .then(res => {
    //             setResponseData(res.data)
    //             console.log(responseData)

    //         }, function (err) {

    //             console.log(err)
    //         })

    // }


    return (
        <div style={{
            color: "black"
        }}>
            <h5>This is {props.userInfo.firstName}'s Profile Page</h5>
            <h5>Last name: {props.userInfo.lastName}</h5>
            <h5>Age: {props.userInfo.age}</h5>
            <h5>Location:{props.userInfo.location}</h5>
            <h5>Image:{props.userInfo.profileImage}</h5>
            <h5>Biography:{props.userInfo.biography}</h5>

            <ImageUploader user={user}/>


            {/* <div className="col-md-6 img">
                <img
                    src={responseData.profileImage}
                    alt="profile image"
                    className="img-rounded"/>
            </div> */}

            <div className="row">

                <DisplayCats user={user}/>
            </div>

            {/*


            <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                onClick={this.clickHandler}
                component={this.EditProfile}
                user={this.props.user}>
                Edit Info
            </Button> */}

        </div>
    )
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

I want my image data and and image name to be created into a URL for my other functions to read it. My error comes back as `POST /api/image/uploadmulter/ 404 97.290 ms - 163`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps im missing something but from the code you shared, you set your route as:

```js
ImageRouter.route("/upload")
```

so, your client side code should be posting to: `http://localhost:5000/upload`

yet, your code does this:

```
.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/image/uploadmulter/`
```

You're getting a 404 error, which makes sense since this route hasn't been defined.

On a related note, I'd recommend using something like [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady), to manage the uploads on your client-side. It will save you a lot of code and bugs. Especially if you want to show [preview](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/tree/master/packages/ui/upload-preview) or other related functionality (like: progress, cancel, retry, etc.).